# Quick OSM request returns a layer which does not match OSM in QGIS

Tags: qgis, qgis-3, quickosm

I made this request from quick osm

```
[timeout:2500]
[maxsize:2000000000];
area[admin_level='6'][ref='90']->.area;
rel(pivot.area)->.rel;
(
node[highway](area.area);
node[highway](r.rel);
way[highway](area.area);
way[highway](r.rel);
rel[highway](area.area);
rel[highway](r.rel);
);
(._;>;);
out;
```

The request works fine but when I want to put the layer of Open Street Map, both layers don't fit together. I tried to change the SCR and when the layer from Quick OSMis in ESPG 4326 and Open street map in 2154 they match.

How can I fix that? My QGIS version: 3.10.14

[image: lines in SCR 2154 and Open street map in 2154]

Comment: Please provide a screenshot of the "don't fit together" issue.

Comment: edit done : layer lines (SCR 2154) is lost in the ocean of Open Street Map (SCR 2154)

Comment: What is "2154"? And what happens if you start with a new project and do not override any CRS?

Comment: Downloads from OSM are usually in WGS 84 (EPSG 4326). Please **set** you line-layer to this CRS and report back.

Comment: Boths layers lines and Open street map match when lines is in ESPG 4326 and OSM in ESPG 3857. Is that normal ?

Comment: Yes, it's normal. When downloading data from OSM with QuickOSM, they are always in EPSG:4326. OSM tiles are always (very very often) in EPSG:3857. To make them match, you indeed need to set these CRS. Then now, you can do a reprojection of your data from 4326 to 2154. So the question is, did you use a the reprojection algorithm in QGIS or did you do a "save as/enregistrer sous" for the given layer and set a new projection ? You must do one of these two to have data in 2154.